# What is 67.63.55.3?

Tags: networking, dns, ping

On my Mac, if I ping a single-word domain, I see:

```
PING asdfsad (67.63.55.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 67.63.55.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=241 time=93.308 ms
64 bytes from 67.63.55.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=241 time=96.837 ms
```

etc.

This happens, as far as I can tell, for any single word.

I would expect it to return `Unknown Host` or some similar error. So why this IP?

**Things I have determined:**

A whois lookup tells me that it is related to [Blucora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blucora)... I've never heard of them before.

Traceroute returns:

```
Traceroute has started…

traceroute to hjhgfjh (67.63.55.3), 64 hops max, 72 byte packets

 1  10.0.1.1 (10.0.1.1)  1.114 ms  0.770 ms  0.729 ms
 2  10.240.184.81 (10.240.184.81)  8.935 ms  9.032 ms  10.116 ms
 3  433be0e1.cst.lightpath.net (67.59.241.225)  15.735 ms  11.319 ms  10.576 ms
 4  rtr1-ge1-3.mhe.whplny.cv.net (67.83.230.1)  14.493 ms  11.433 ms  15.134 ms
 5  r1-ge6-1.cst.nrwlct.cv.net (65.19.121.161)  16.598 ms  18.305 ms
    65.19.121.37 (65.19.121.37)  14.023 ms
 6  64.15.3.241 (64.15.3.241)  16.570 ms
    64.15.3.230 (64.15.3.230)  17.813 ms
    64.15.3.218 (64.15.3.218)  14.089 ms
 7  64.15.0.102 (64.15.0.102)  37.643 ms  37.702 ms  34.019 ms
 8  chi2-pr1-ae5-115.us.twtelecom.net (66.192.252.97)  35.458 ms  35.082 ms  34.808 ms
 9  sea1-ar3-xe-1-0-0-0.us.twtelecom.net (66.192.250.14)  98.257 ms  94.150 ms  116.695 ms
10  66-193-100-94.static.twtelecom.net (66.193.100.94)  94.599 ms  92.712 ms  94.271 ms
11  tuk01ef01-reth4.0.inspinc.ad (67.63.56.61)  95.860 ms  96.067 ms  96.450 ms
12  67.63.55.3 (67.63.55.3)  93.160 ms  92.671 ms  98.431 ms
```

So this establishes that it is an ISP thing, not an issue with my router/computer, right? Though isn't odd that my request is handled seemingly without an error, routed through my ISP (Optimum), though to Cablevision and tw Telecomm?

Then there is that last domain, `inspinc.ad`, which also tracks back to Blucora... visiting `inspinc.ad` doesn't work, and I can't ping it, but `inspinc.com` as well as `inspinc.eu` return `Status: OK` with no other information.

In my googling I was unable to find any answers, but I did find numerous results of people having this IP show up with invalid pings.

Comment: May I ask the downvoter for his/her objections?

Comment: Downvoter probably thinks you're jumping to conclusions without covering the basics. You probably get the same result for any nonexistent domain, not just single word.

Comment: Fair enough, however  I did determine that things like "dragaste.esrgwe" just say unknown host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that your DNS server is returning that address for gibberish domain requests.

If you run `nslookup asdfsad` in Terminal you'll see what DNS server is being queried.

When you access that IP in a web browser, you get back a not found page from Optimum online. My guess is that Optimum is your ISP, and they have configured your DNS servers to return a customized page to your browser when you access a domain that doesn't exist, rather than just let the browser fail.

You can experiment with defining your own DNS servers to override this behavior. People will commonly use [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com) services if they don't like or trust their ISPs, and OpenDNS will also catch common misspellings and redirect you to the right place (this also makes your browser safer if a misspelled domain is taken over by a phisher). Google also provides an easy-to-remember public DNS.

OpenDNS:

```
208.67.222.222
208.67.220.220
```

Google Public DNS:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen you mentioned Optimum in your answer when I wrote this.

Comment: Yes, it does appear that the ISP is highjacking the DNS to show a 'domain not found' page. https://gwhois.org/response/?q=67.63.55.3

Comment: Ok, I had seen that page before but not thought much of it (as I often see that page for unknown hosts). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out Optimum isn't as bad* as I thought. When navigating to one of these non-existent domains in my browser, I am shown the hijacked Optimum DNS Assistance page... with an option to opt-out of the service!

So opt out I did, and now all of my invalid DNS lookups return `NXDOMAIN`, as they should.

Granted, this only applies to Optimum customers, but it does serve as a reminder to look for a simpler solution first...

I'm going to leave NReilingh's answer as the accepted answer because that applies for everyone, not just Optimum customers.

*they're still *pretty* bad.